# Set the distance of all selected objects to another object to be the same

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects

I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem. There are several objects whose size and position are identical. And there is a single terrain mesh. I want to position these objects with always the same distance to terrain mesh.

I want the white objects to be positioned where the red objects are drawn:

[image]

Can this be solved with a script, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Misunderstood i think , whites should be red after something..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a *Shrinkwrap* constraint. Select one of your objects give it the constraint, and adjust the projection direction and distance as you like:

[image]

Here, I'm copying the constraint to the other objects using the shipped add-on - 'Interface: Copy Attributes Menu'. But it can be done through Header > Object > Constraints.

If you want to apply the constraints and get rid of them, that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Visual, followed by 'Clear Object Constraints', again, from the header menu.

Answer (score 4):

Alternate version with Geometry Nodes:

Set a Vertex Group:

[image]

Instance along that Vertex Group by converting it to a Curve:

[image]

- The diamond shaped 'Selection' Node can be set in the Modifiers Properties, click the cross icon and then click the blank field and select your Vertex group
- Number of instances is set with Count in the Resample Curve Node
- Distance from surface is the Z Axis in Set Position node